# how can you cbind elements from a list with unequal lengths?

Tags: r, list

If I have a list `x` with 3 elements the data.frames `a`, `b` and `c`, how do I run the function `FUNC` that requires the three dataframes like `FUN(x$a, x$b, x$c)`?

Example data

```
my.list <- list(data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2)),
                data.frame(y2 = c(3, 2, 1)),
                data.frame(y3 = c(7, 8, 4,5,6)))
names(my.list) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

The main issue I have is that `my.list` may sometimes have elements `a`, `b` and `c`, and sometimes `e` and/or `f` so I want a method to call the elements that don't depend on the element's name nor the number of elements.

I have been trying

```
 do.call(cbind, my.list)
```

but I get the error message

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3, 5

Comment: So do you want to `cbind` each list elements 1st column?

Comment: For the sake of this example, yes.

Comment: [`do.call(fun, list)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call)

Comment: Like this : `do.call(cbind, my.list)` ?

Comment: ok yes!, Thanks that works brilliantly for the example. The problem with my real data is that the function id a customised one that essentially does `cbind` for vectors with unequal lengths by filling the gaps with `NA`. Could you work that out and I'll change the example accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unequal number of rows in each dataframe, you first need to make them of same length and then `cbind` :

```
n <- max(sapply(my.list, nrow))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(my.list, function(x) x[1:n, , drop = FALSE]))
rownames(out) <- NULL
out

#  y1 y2 y3
#1  1  3  7
#2  2  2  8
#3 NA  1  4
#4 NA NA  5
#5 NA NA  6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
do.call(cbind.fill, c(my.list, fill = NA))
```